Bounded geometric morphisms, origin and motivation for the terminology
Bounded geometric morphisms serve as a generalization of Grothendieck topoi; $T$ being a Grothendieck topos iff global section $T \rightarrow Set$ is bounded. I managed to only track this down to the Johnstone's, 1977 Topos theory, where it is defined, but the terminology "bound"/"bounded" isn't motivated.
The definition of Bounded geometric morphism 4.43, is attributed to "W. Mitchell", but none of the 3 references by Mitchell (William Mitchell, the only Mitchell in the bibliography as a sole author) in the bibliography seem to use the terms "bound"/"bounded" or discuss a similar definition on a skim.
This results in 3 questions:

What's the motivation for calling these geometric morphisms bounded, calling part of the definition a "bound"?
What's the original text defining and hopefully motivating the terminology "bounded"?
Is there a precise connection with order theoretical bounded?

The 3 references by William Mitchell being:

"Categories of Boolean Topoi"
"On topoi as closed categories"
"Boolean topoi and the theory of sets"


I don't know the motivation (asking on the category theory mailing list might be a good idea, Johnstone is still active - I can do it if you can't), but what a bound does is place a set-sized upper bound on a class of generators. Once you have a topos $F$ with a geometric morphism to $\mathbf{Set}$ (eg a locally small topos) you can ask how big a generating class is, and if this is small aka a set, then you know it's a Grothendieck topos. A bounded geometric morphism asks the same question but for a geom. morphism $p\colon F\to E$, and expresses it in terms of $p$.

@DavidRoberts Thanks that makes sense. Which mailing list would this be? Having the story from the source would be useful.

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/categories+mailing+list but I need to track down how to subscribe and update that page, as it doesn't say how!

Aha, you have to email JS Lemay to subscribe to it: see instructions here https://sites.google.com/view/jspl-personal-webpage/

I have sent an email to the list asking the question about the terminology 'bound'

Here is what Peter Johnstone wrote on the matter in response to me passing on the question:

I was certainly around at the time that terminology came into use, and I may have been the first person to use it in print (in my 1977 book). In his 1975 paper "Change of base for toposes with generators", Radu Diaconescu referred to a topos F "having generators" over a base E, but that seemed a bit cumbersome;  the single word "bounded" had the right overtones, in that it referred to a single object of F (which I later took to calling simply a "bound") that controlled how complicated the objects could be relative to those of E. I don't know whether I actually suggested the term, but as far as I can recall everyone agreed that it was a sensible choice.
Incidentally, the Grothendieck school were aware of the existence of what we would call unbounded Set-toposes, only they didn't consider them to be toposes. (There is one described in SGA4 as a "faux topos".)


A bounded geometric morphism $f:\mathcal E\to \mathcal S$ is one that has a bound $B$, i.e. an object such that all of $\mathcal E$ is "below" $f^*(\mathcal S)$ relative to $B$, in the sense of being a subquotient of $f^* S\times B$ for some $S.$ In motivating examples, $B$ might be constructed as a coproduct over a small set of generating objects, as for instance in the Artin gluing of an accessible Set-functor, whose bound is explicitly constructed using a coproduct of sets smaller than the cardinal bound $\kappa.$ Similarly, the bound for a Grothendieck topos can always be taken as the coproduct of all $\kappa$-presentable objects for sufficiently large $\kappa.$ So you might imagine boundedness is intended to call up the intuition of a cardinal bound in this sense. I do not know whether there's an appropriate notion of indexed local presentability making this intuition more precise, nor whether this is historically accurate; I personally think that the properties of $B$ as given at the beginning of my answer have the feel of a bound without going any further.
